# Set folder permissions to 0444 but now cannot cd in

Tags: linux

I have a folder which contains files. These files are no-longer to change, so from outside the directory I ran:

`chmod 0444' <folder_name>`

However, when I now do:

`cd <folder_name>`

I get:

`bash: cd: <folder_name>: Permission denied`

the permissions look like:

`dr--r--r--`

Why can't I `cd` in to the folder if it's read-only? I only want to prevent the files being modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need at least the Execute permission on a directory to cd to it.  Do

```
chmod 500 FOO
```

if you only want to access it yourself, or

```
chmod 555 FOO
```

to make it accessible (but of course not writable) by others.